# Trying to set up my JDK, when I enter "echo %JAVA_HOME%" it shows my JDK location but doesn't allow me compile any code

Tags: java

I've been to numerous sites and have made all the paths. When I type "echo %JAVA_HOME%" into the command, it shows the location as it's supposed to. But when I try and compile code it responds with "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I don't know much about how it's supposed to work and the internet doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What is the command you use to compile your code?

Comment: What you see in JAVA_HOME when you echo it?

Comment: Setting `JAVA_HOME` doesn't make Java available from the command-line. You don't need to set `JAVA_HOME` at all, just to run `javac` and `java` from the command-line. You need to add `C:\path\to\java\bin` to the **PATH** instead.

Comment: What is the output if you 'echo %PATH%'?

Comment: Follow this tutorial : https://www.codejava.net/java-core/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-windows-10

Comment: Hey Kitty, to make it easier for people to answer your question, try to give as much relevant information as you can: What OS are you using? How exactly did you install JRE? What installation guides have you already tried? Did you encounter errors in the process?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is just run a simple "Hello World" system.out.printLn in IntelliJ. Using a simple "javac.Main.java" command.

Comment: I followed the tutorial that Peter Parker has posted and nothing has changed, although I'm not getting the exact outcome the end has. But a similar output.

Comment: I'm on windows 10, I downloaded it from Oracle. There weren't any installation errors to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your system path variable to your java's bin directory

For eg. my path variable is like:

```
C:\java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin
```

OR you can do like

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin
```

JAVA_HOME is variable which is used by other application like maven to refer JAVA home directory.

Comment: Maven uses `JAVA_HOME`. However, the path is used to detect the location of binaries when just running them without a location. And there are multiple entries in the `PATH`, not only java.

Comment: Yes dan1st, that's why we need to add java bin location to path or we can give absolute path of binaries

Comment: I know. I just wanted to note that. Imagine the OP setting the `PATH` to java only.